# Determining Cause of valueForKeyPath exceptions

Tags: ios, objective-c

Recently I changed some Core Data models in a project I was working on. The migration went fine, but I had some wrappers on the objects that did lookups on keypaths (ie: valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.somePropertyThatNoLongerExists"), and the app crashed.

I eventually stumbled across that portion of my code by break pointing step-by-step through to see at what point it crashed, but there was no Strack Trace, no $eax, or any other indicator that I'm aware of that told me where the problem was.

My question is, with valueForKeyPath calls, is there any way to determine when/where you've gone wrong? As far as I know, it does throw an exception (so obviously I could wrap it with try/catch), but most other things that throw are traceable back to their origin, right?

Comment: it means the value(sum) you are calculating ,that variable is no longer exist in your coredata, or maybe mis spelled. check it and you will solve it.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara As I mentioned, I knew what the error was caused by. What I was asking, though, was how to determine where that error was coming from.

Comment: "I eventually stumbled across that portion of my code by break pointing step-by-step through to see at what point it crashed". You should look into setting an Exception Breakpoint to do this for you. Just open the "Breakpoint Navigator" and click the "+" all the way at the bottom left then choose "Add Exception Breakpoint". Choose all of the default values and click "Done". Now run your app and anytime there is an exception, execution will pause on the line that is causing the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can trace the problem by adding [all exceptions break point, as described in this blog post.](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions)

Comment: Wow (facepalm). I'm entirely familiar with the exception breakpoint, but I had recently deleted and re-cloned the project, so that was gone, and I never re-added it. Thanks for reminding me.